# ArgumentError in joinedload

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these models:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users_user'
    ...
    country = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('countries.id'))


class Country(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'countries'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    user_country = db.relationship('User', backref='user_country', lazy='joined')
```

---

I am trying this query:

```
User.query.options(joinedload(Country.user_country)).filter_by(id=current_user.get_id()).first()
```

That will throw this error:

```
ArgumentError: Can't find property 'user_country' on any entity specified in this Query.
Note the full path from root (Mapper|User|users_user) to target entity must be specified.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Why not just use `current_user.user_country`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `joinedload` here is unnecessary.

By default relationships are lazily-loaded. This causes additional `SELECT` queries to be issued to retrieve the data. `joinedload` is one of the ways to force the relationship to be eagerly loaded by using a `JOIN` instead.

In this case, however, you've defaulted the relationship between `User` and `Country` to use eager loading by specifying `lazy='joined'`. This would reduce your query to

```
User.query.filter(id=current_user.get_id()).first()
```

While this will help you with the `ArgumentError`, we can go a little further. The query itself is unnecessary as well. `current_user` already has the data for its related `Country` because of the eager join. Accessing `current_user.user_country` will not send any additional queries to the database.